# How to left align Text but centre fa=home icon

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to left align text, but center align fa=home icon see below

```
<div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <h4 class="card-header">Accomdation</h4>
    <div class="card-body">
    <i class="fa fa-home"; style="font-size:96px; align-content: center"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text-center class to  as below :

```
<div class="card-body text-center">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <h4 class="card-header">Accomdation</h4>
    <div class="card-body text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <h4 class="card-header">Accomdation</h4>
    <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center;border:1px solid #eee">
    <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:96px;"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the  `d-flex flex-column align-items-center` classes on card-body

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card" style="width:300px">
  <h4 class="card-header">Accomdation</h4>
  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
    <i class="fa fa-home" ; style="font-size:96px; align-content: center"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
      <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="card" style="width:300px">
    <h4 class="card-header">Accomdation</h4>
    <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

if you want to use CSS
add `text-align: center` to respective div